# Почему сливаются col1 и col2 при применении float:left?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```css
.container{
  width: 1250px;
  background-color:blue; 
  height: 500px;
}
.col1,.col2,.col3{
  margin:10px;
  width:200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border:2px solid white; 
 }
.col1{
  float: left;
  border:2px solid white;
  margin-right:100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1"><span>col1</span></div>
  <div class="col2"><span>col2</span></div>
  <div class="col3"><span>col3</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: зачем использовать float, при размещении блоков в одну колонку?

Comment: Просто хотел разобраться со свойством float))

Answer (score 3):

Эт схлопывание называется. Следующему элементу необходимо `clear:both` прописать.
Если используете Bootstrap, то там есть класс `.clearfix` для этих целей.

> Для float, родственное свойство - clear. Любой элемент, у которого установлено свойство clear, не будет поднят вверх, как от него ожидается, а отобразится ниже, после float-элементов.

Почитайте [здесь](http://www.css-tricks.ru/articles/css/all-about-floats)

```css
.container{
  width: 1250px;
  background-color:blue; 
  height: 500px;
}
.col1,.col2,.col3{
  margin:10px;
  width:200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border:2px solid white; 
 }
.col1{
  float: left;
  border:2px solid white;
  margin-right:100px; 
}
.col2{
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1"><span>col1</span></div>
  <div class="col2"><span>col2</span></div>
  <div class="col3"><span>col3</span></div>
</div>
```